# Placing code at specific (low) virtual memory addresses

Tags: c, assembly, linker, ld, riscv

I want to run a virtual memory setup on a RISC-V simulator (Spike). As I am trying to emulate embedded/real-time devices I do not want large page tables and so want to place the code in very low virtual memory addresses.

The linker script I have at the moment places `.text` at VMA/LMA `0x80000000`. I want to keep the initialisation code at this (high) physical address and indeed place the remaining code also at high addresses, but after I have set up the system I want to jump to a `main(0, 0)` at a low virtual memory address.

How do I structure a linker script like this? Do I assign VMAs to all symbols? That seems very difficult to manage.

To explain further - I have a `crt.S` file which has the start up code, it then transfers control to a C file - syscalls.c (this provides some very basic 'system calls') the `_init` function of which calls `main(0, 0)` in whatever program I am building (ie the crt.S and syscalls.c are linked with the 'interesting' code in each case. I want the syscalls.c stuff to be handled outside of VM mode and the interesting code to be handled in VM).

If you want to see the code it's at: https://github.com/mcmenaminadrian/taclebench-riscv-baremetal (riscv branch)